# Display table when hovering over row of another table

Tags: html, css, hover, css-tables

I would like to display a certain table when the user hovers over the row of another table without using any JS. I have seen solutions for similar things but they require your elements to be descendent, child or adjacent elements. I would like the tables to be properly seperated though. Kind of like:

```css
#HS {
  display: none;
}

#Uni {
  display: none;
}

#HSrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(167, 177, 189);
}

.HSrow:hover+.HS {
  display: block;
}

.HSrow:hover+.Uni {
  display: block;
}

#Unirow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(167, 177, 189);
  color: black;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-family: din6776;
  font-size: var(--fs-body);
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-image: url(../img/Body_6.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 0 5vw 10vh 5vw;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 97, 182, 0.7);
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">*,
  <table id="Edu" style="width:35vw">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Timespan</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr id="HSrow">
      <th>09.2010 – 11.2014</th>
      <td>HS</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Unirow">
      <th>10.2012 – 01.2013</th>
      <td>University 2</td>
      <td>Laboratory</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="HS" style="width:35vw">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="texthead" colspan="6">HS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="Description">Version</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">Name</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">Date</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>V 1.0</td>
        <td colspan="3">John Doe</td>
        <td colspan="3">12345</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">lalala</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">lalala</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">lalala</td>
        <td colspan="3">lalala</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="Uni" style="width:35vw">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="texthead" colspan="6">Uni</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="Description">Version</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">Name</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">Date</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>V 1.0</td>
        <td colspan="3">John Doe</td>
        <td colspan="3">12345</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">lalala</td>
        <td id="Description" colspan="3">lalala</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">lalala</td>
        <td colspan="3">lalala</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would like the table with the id "HS" to pop up when I hover over "HSrow" and the same for the Uni table.
Is it possible without JS?

Best Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulate the bootstrap side popover without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420617/emulate-the-bootstrap-side-popover-without-javascript)

Comment: Not really.
1. He is still using a JS function
2. The popover is a child of the button. I don't see how I could make a table a child of the row of another table.

I'm not 100% strict on the "not using JS" as I get the feeling that this is not possible with just CSS

Comment: Where he use js? i think is not possible do what you want without js

Comment: The answer from david uses the toggleclass function.
The code in the original question does not use this but the popout is static so that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds this later, I have been able to solve this using "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" together with a "makevis" and "makinvis" command:

```
<tr class="hover" onmouseover="makevis('HStable')" onmouseout="makeinvis('HStable')">
```